# Chapter-Header Font Size - Too Big

Tags: margins, chapters, fontsize

I'm using the `book` class for a particular document, and I've run into a bit of problem. I don't know exactly how to explain this, so I'll just post an explanatory picture instead of sounding obscure.

[image: iu]

As you can see, that chapter-header is bleeding way too much. Is there a way to change the font size for that?

**P.S:** I know I should probably change the chapter title if it's that long, but I'd like to know how to solve this problem anyway.

Comment: Use the optional argument for `\chapter` like `\chapter[here]{long heading}`. It is not big BTW but all cpas.

Comment: Use a *short title* for your heading `\chapter[short title]{Long Title ...}`. The font size can be changed with the packages `fancyhdr` or `titlesec`.